# How to test the logic of a catch block using xUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net

At work I have a function that generically does this:

```
        public SomeObject MethodWithTryCatch()
        {
            //some logic
            try
            {
                //some logic that may throw an exception
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                return new SomeObject
                {
                    //list of properties
                    ErrorMessage = exception.Message
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to test a couple things:

1. that indeed an exception was caught
2. and that the returned object is equivalent to the one I expected

Questions:

1. is it possible to "trip" the method directly into the catch block?
2. because`ErrorMessage = exception.Message` how can I make sure the expected object and actual object will have the same `ErrorMessage` value?
3. generally how do you test something like this using xUnit?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Assert.Throws` statement to verify the exception is raised.

eg

```
[Fact]
public void VerifyCatch()
{
   
    var f = new Foo();
   
    var e = Assert.Throws<SomeException>(() => f.MyMethod());
    Assert.Equal("My expected message", e.Message);
}
```